# Linked List with Pointer and Struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, valgrind

I've tried to program a linked list with pointer and struct in c. On console my little example is working but as soon as I want to check what **valgrind** returns, the output below appears.

I think it's something like a **out of bounds** exception, but I don't know how to interpret and to solve it the right way.

**Source-Code:**

```
int main(){
  struct node {
      int data;
      struct node *nextNode;
  };

  int counter = 10;
  struct node *nodeSpace;

  nodeSpace = (struct node *) malloc(counter * sizeof(struct node));
  struct node *base = nodeSpace;

  for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
      int offset = i * sizeof(struct node);
      struct node *currentNode;

      currentNode = base + offset;
      currentNode->data = i;

      if(i == counter-1)
          currentNode->nextNode = NULL;
      else
          currentNode->nextNode = base + (i+1)*sizeof(struct node);

      printf("Node (%i): Address: %p Data: %i Next: %p\n", 
             i, currentNode, currentNode->data, currentNode->nextNode);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

**Valgrind:**

```
Node (0): Address: 0x5203040 Data: 0 Next: 0x5203140
Node (1): Address: 0x5203140 Data: 1 Next: 0x5203240
Node (2): Address: 0x5203240 Data: 2 Next: 0x5203340
Node (3): Address: 0x5203340 Data: 3 Next: 0x5203440
Node (4): Address: 0x5203440 Data: 4 Next: 0x5203540
==23418== Invalid write of size 4
==23418==    at 0x4005DC: main (linkedList.c:18)
==23418==  Address 0x5203540 is 32 bytes before an unallocated block of size 4,192,896 in arena "client"
==23418==
```

The error from valgrind appears in line

```
currentNode->data = i;
```

If someone could help me, it would be really nice, thanks.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic will do the `sizeof` calculation for you. `offset` doesn't need it. And pick **a** language.

Comment: Time for [Binky](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/104/) again?-)

Comment: Just a side note, You may write `nodeSpace = (struct node *) malloc(counter * sizeof(struct node));`  as `nodeSpace = malloc(counter * sizeof *node);`. In short you may not caste the o/p of `malloc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typed pointer arithmetic retains the stride of the underlying element as part of the address calculation. It is the reason, given a non-`void` type pointer `p`, that

```
p[i]
```

and

```
*(p+i)
```

are synonymous.

To see the automatic use of element width, consider:

```
int ar[2];
int *p = ar;
int *q = p+1;

printf("p = %p\n", (const void*)p);
printf("q = %p\n", (const void*)q);
```

Sample Output (varies)

```
p = 0x7fff5fbff9d0
q = 0x7fff5fbff9d4
```

Note the size of an `int` is already accounted for (in this case, it's four bytes).

That said, your code reduces to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    struct node
    {
        int data;
        struct node *nextNode;
    };

    int counter = 10;
    struct node *nodeSpace = malloc(counter * sizeof(struct node));

    for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        struct node *currentNode = nodeSpace + i;
        currentNode->data = i;

        if(i == counter-1)
            currentNode->nextNode = NULL;
        else
            currentNode->nextNode = currentNode+1;

        printf("Node (%i): Address: %p Data: %i Next: %p\n",
               i, currentNode, currentNode->data, currentNode->nextNode);
    }

    free(nodeSpace);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output** (example)

```
Node (0): Address: 0x1001053a0 Data: 0 Next: 0x1001053b0
Node (1): Address: 0x1001053b0 Data: 1 Next: 0x1001053c0
Node (2): Address: 0x1001053c0 Data: 2 Next: 0x1001053d0
Node (3): Address: 0x1001053d0 Data: 3 Next: 0x1001053e0
Node (4): Address: 0x1001053e0 Data: 4 Next: 0x1001053f0
Node (5): Address: 0x1001053f0 Data: 5 Next: 0x100105400
Node (6): Address: 0x100105400 Data: 6 Next: 0x100105410
Node (7): Address: 0x100105410 Data: 7 Next: 0x100105420
Node (8): Address: 0x100105420 Data: 8 Next: 0x100105430
Node (9): Address: 0x100105430 Data: 9 Next: 0x0
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your detailed answer

Comment: When printing a memory address of a variable,  there is no need to typecast to (const void *).  You can do simply  printf("p = %p\n", p) instead of printf("q = %p\n", (const void*)p);